# List container with three parts, want the middle to expand to fill height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a container made of a header, a body and footer.
Header needs to be able to move a bit (which seems to work fine by setting a max height), body quite a bit more, and my footer is a fixed height. The overall mapsidebar container can not grow to more of 400px and when that happens i would like to have the header and footer always visible, and the body having a scroll bar appearing.

I'm having issues having the body expand to fill the height of the container.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a bit new to SA so I always hope I provided enough information.

A note on the behaviour, the listofplaces gets populated by user generated content so it can be one list item or 20.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mapsidebar">
            <div id="listheader">
                <div id="mapTitleLbl" tabindex="2">Untitled Map</div>
                <input id="mapTitleInput" type="text" maxlength="45" tabindex="-1"/>
                <div id="mapDescriptionLbl" tabindex="3">Map Description</div>
                <textarea id="mapDescriptionInput"rows="4" cols="4" maxlength="130" tabindex="-1"> </textarea> 
           </div>               
            <div id="listbody">
                <div class="places"><ol id="listofplaces"></ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="listfooter">
                <div id="count"><font id="countView" weight="bold">0</font> views
                </div> 
                <div id="share">
                    <div id="zerocopydiv" title="Copy map link to your clipboard"></div>
                    <a id="facebookpopup" title="Share to facebook" href=""></a>   
                    <a id="twitterpopup" title="Share to twitter" href=""></a>
                    <div id="sharetext">Share this map</div> 
                </div>
                <div id="lockPanel">
                    <div id="unlockable">This map is editable by everyone.</div>
                    <div id ="unlock"><a id="lockcheck" href="" title="Lock/Unlock this map" onclick="javascript:onUnlockClick();return false;"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#mapsidebar {
position: absolute;
top: 215px;
right: 0px;
background-color: #fff;
color: #41414C;
font-size: 13px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bab9b9;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bab9b9;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bab9b9;
overflow: auto;
padding: 0;
opacity: 0.95;
width: 200px;
border: 3px solid #E6E6E6;}

#listheader{
max-height: 168px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #e6e6e6;
overflow-y: scroll;}

#listbody{
min-height:150px;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;}

.places{
overflow-y: scroll;}

#listofplaces,
#listofplaces li{
padding: 0px 0px 5px;
margin: 0 0 0 14px;}

#listfooter {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;}
```

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/G4uEj/

Comment: Hi Afshin and thank you for your answer. I clarified my question, I need to mapsidebar's height to hit a max of 400px and when that happens, the listbody being the one growing, to show a sidebar to accomodate for that. Is it doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ficho, have a look at this jsfiddle. The changes I made to your CSS will allow the body to grow infinitely while still keeping the footer at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/GC3yn/

I removed the min-height from the #listbody because it didn't make sense to have unnecessary whitespace if the list had no items.

I also removed the absolute positioning and height from the footer because it should always appear at the bottom of #mapsidebar due to the page flow of HTML elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot for your help. Actually I need to contain the max height of the mapsidebar to something like 400px, and when i do that, the growinglistbody pushes down the listfooter. Do you know how I could do it? I'm editing the question to clarify

Comment: #mapsidebar should only ever be 400px tall and the #listbody should scroll, but only if its contents make the height greater than 200px.

Comment: So i need to set #mapsidebar max-height to 400px and listbody to overflow-y:scroll? I try but it behaves oddly

Comment: Actually nvm it works :) Do you know why the scroolbars dont appear (in chrome)